# Distribution function and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

This might be a strange question and I'm completely confused.

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and $\xi:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the c.d.f. of $\xi$, i.e., $F(x)=P(\xi\leq x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. My question is whether $E(\xi|F(\xi))=\xi$, where $F(\xi)$ is the composition of $F$ and $\xi$. Of course the question boils down to whether $\xi$ is measurable with respect to $F(\xi)$.

What makes me confused is the following example. Consider $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathscr{F}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $P$ be the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$, and $\xi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\xi(x)=x$. Then clearly $\xi$ is not measurable w.r.t. $F(\xi)$ and hence $E(\xi|F(\xi))\neq \xi$. But if we restrict attention to $\Omega=[0,1]$, $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{B}([0,1])$, then $\xi$ is measurable w.r.t. $F(\xi)$ and hence $E(\xi|F(\xi))=\xi$.

It seems to me $F(\xi)$ contains all relevant information about $\xi$, but $\xi$ is not measurable w.r.t $F(\xi)$ because some measure 0 sets. Is there any general statement about $E(\xi|F(\xi))=\xi$?

Comment: If you know $F(\xi)=t$, you know that $\xi=F^{-1}(t)$ - other values that give $t$ are within a ball of probability zero so no need to consider them. Hence $E(\xi|F(\xi))=\xi$ $F$-a.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general statement you can make in your counterexample is $E(\xi\mid F(\xi))=\xi$ almost surely.

Conditional expectations are equal except on a set of measure zero. That is, if $Y$ and $Y'$ both satisfy the requirements for $E(X\mid\mathscr G)$, then $P(Y=Y')=1$. In your counterexample it is true that $\xi$ is not measurable with respect to $F(\xi)$ when $\Omega=\mathbb R$; however, there is a version $\xi'$ that equals $\xi$ with prob 1 such that $\xi'$ *is* measurable and $E(\xi\mid F(\xi))=\xi'$, namely $\xi':=F(\xi)$.

The result $E(\xi\mid F(\xi))=\xi$ a.s. is true in general. Write $\mathscr G:=\sigma(F(\xi))$ and let $\mathscr G^*$ be the completion of $\mathscr G$, i.e., $\mathscr G^*$ is the sigma-algebra consisting of all $A\cup Z$ where $A\in\mathscr G$ and $Z$ is a subset of a set of probability zero. Argue that $\xi$ is measurable with respect to $\mathscr G^*$, and therefore $\xi$ is a version of $E(\xi\mid\mathscr G^*)$. But any version of $E(\xi\mid\mathscr G)$ is also a version of $E(\xi\mid\mathscr G^*)$, and therefore equals $\xi$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks. When you write $E(\xi|F(\xi))=\xi$, do you mean "Any version of $E(\xi|F(\xi))$ is equal to $\xi$ almost surely"? Since usually, when we write $E(\xi|\mathscr{G})=\eta$ we mean $\eta$ is a version of $E(\xi|\mathscr{G})$.

Comment: Yep, any version of $E(\xi\mid F(\xi))$ is equal to $\xi$ almost surely.

Comment: I agree. But as you noted, this only works for the very special example I gave.

Comment: Now I think the general statement is also true. Any version of $E(\xi|F(\xi))$ is equal to $\xi$ almost surely.

Comment: @user295959 Agreed, see edit above. The subtle part is proving that $\xi$ is measurable with respect to the completion of $\sigma(F(\xi))$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I showed is the following: for every $B\in\sigma(\xi)$, there exists $B'\in\sigma(F(\xi))$ such that $P(B\triangle B')=0$. This means $\xi$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(\sigma(F(\xi)), \mathcal{N})$ where $\mathcal{N}$ is the set of all zero measure sets in $\mathscr{F}$. This sigma algebra is potentially smaller than the completion of $\sigma(F(\xi))$ when $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ is not complete.